# How to compress all files with exception of newest file in each subfolder of a folder into one ZIP file per subfolder?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command, zip, 7zip

I'm trying to create a batch script that will zip all the contents in each subdirectory except the latest (or latest few).  I'm currently attempting in Windows with 7-Zip but the directory is technically on a Linux server so any suggestions geared towards a Linux command is welcome.

The directory structure is like this:

```
Directory-Parent
 ---Sub-Directory-1
 --------File1
 --------File2
 --------File3
 ---Sub-Directory-2
 --------File1
 --------File2
```

I would like to run a batch at the `Directory-Parent` level that will create a zip in each sub-directory of all the files except the latest 1 (or few if possible). I also want to add the year to the end of the zip file name.

So the result would be:

```
Directory-Parent
 -Sub-Directory-1
 --------File1
 --------Sub-Directory-12019.zip
 ---Sub-Directory-2
 --------File1
 --------Sub-Directory-22019.zip
```

I've tried a nested `for` loop but can't seem to get it. I've tried the `for` command with skip and `dir`  in the set (IN), but can't get it to work.

I currently have the following script.

```
SET theYear=2019
For /D %%d in (*.*) do 7z a "%%d\%%d%theYear%.zip" ".\%%d\*"
```

This accomplishes it all except I don't know how to exclude the latest file (newest file according to last modification time) in each folder.

Comment: very good first Q! And a very good job of illustrating your problem with a simplified "picture" of the problem. But ... ;-) ... we need to see a filename that is more representative of the latest file. You'll need to temporarily hid it (rename as `file1.HID` and then use `for /D %%d in (*.txt)...` (just an example), or come up with another way of skipping the newest file. Coming up with a way to programatically identify this file is the crux of your problem and you'd do well to add information to your Q so we can help. All IMHO, Good luck!

Comment: Ahem, @aschipfl found another way to isolate the newest file. I didn't think it was possibl in `.bat` coding, but glad to be proved wrong! Good luck to all.

Comment: @shelter, Thank you for your praise of my first question :)  The files are all the same type (extension) but with different names. I never thought of "hiding it" exactly but I toyed with the idea of moving all but the latest...and there lies the same problem, identifying the latest within the batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch file can be used for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FilesToIgnore=1"
set "theYear=%DATE:~-4%"
set "ListFile=%Temp%\%~n0.lst"
del "%ListFile%" 2>nul
for /D %%I in (*) do call :CompressFiles "%%I"
goto EndBatch

:CompressFiles
pushd %1
set "ZipFile=%~nx1%theYear%.zip"
for /F "skip=%FilesToIgnore% eol=| delims=" %%J in ('dir /A-D /B /O-D /TW 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /C:"%ZipFile%"') do >>"%ListFile%" echo %%J
if exist "%ListFile%" (
    echo Compressing files in directory %1 ...
    7z.exe a -bd -bso0 -i"@%ListFile%" -mx9 -scsDOS -- "%ZipFile%"
    del "%ListFile%"
)
popd
goto :EOF

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The batch file sets environment variable `theYear` dynamically from region dependent date string of dynamic environment variable `DATE`. Please execute in a command prompt window `echo %DATE:~-4%` and verify if output is the current year because of `echo %DATE%` outputs current local date with last four characters being the year.

The batch file ignores the `FilesToIgnore` newest files in each directory. Ignored is also the ZIP file if already existing from a previous execution of the batch file. The ZIP file is never included in number of `FilesToIgnore` because of filtered out already by `findstr` which filters output of command `dir` which outputs the file names without path in current directory ordered by last modification time with newest files output first and oldest files output last.

Please read help of *7-Zip* for the used switches and parameters.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**Update:** *7-Zip* version 19.00.0.0 outputs a warning and creates an empty ZIP file in each subdirectory on using the command line as written below and used initially in batch file. I first thought this is a bug of *7-Zip* version 19.00.0.0 because of this version should support also `--` according to its help and *7-Zip* version 16.04.0.0 works on using the command line:

```
7z.exe a -bd -bso0 -mx9 -scsDOS -- "%ZipFile%" "@%ListFile%"
```

It was necessary to remove `--` from this command line to get it working with **7-Zip** version 19.00.0.0.

So I [reported this issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/2221/) and the author of 7-Zip quickly replied explaining why the usage of `--` results in searching for a file starting with `@` in file name since *7-Zip* version 19.00.0.0:

> We need some way to add `@file` and `-file` names from command line.
> So `--` stops `@` and `-` parsing, and 7-Zip searches exact names.
> It's more safe to use `-i@listfile` instead.

So I updated the batch file code and specify the list file with option `-i`  which is the most safe method to specify a list file.

Comment: Thanks @Mofi!  This did not work at first.  I removed the "-bd -bso0 -mx9 -scsDOS -- " portion of the 7z command and that did the trick.  Amazing!  Thanks again.  For the record and for anyone else looking for something similar aschipfl's solution also works.

Comment: One added question @Mofi.  Is there a way to get it to go through the directories in order (alphabetically)?  I added a pause and an echo in testing to watch what it's doing.  I wanted to try it on the real files that I need this for and slowly step through it the first time but it chose a random folder the first step.

Comment: @skatercurt `for /D %%I in (*) do` results in processing the subdirectories in order as returned by the file system. On NTFS partitions the order is a locale specific alphabetic order. On FAT16, FAT32 and exFAT drives the order is not sorted at all by the file system because of FAT file systems do not sort the file entries at all. It is possible to use `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD-H /B /ON 2^>nul') do` for the first __for__ command line to process the non-hidden subdirectories in current directory ordered by name sorted by `dir` independent on file system sort order.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help!  You really know your stuff.  It does show the progress indication without the ```-bd``` in there and if I add it back it goes away so you're correct.  The -mx9 was way to slow for me so I set it at 5.  I've added the  findstr to the first for loop with the /g switch so I can create a text file of folders names that I want to exclude from being processed.   Again thanks for everything, this will save me a lot of time (and space :) )

Answer (score 1):

The following code is **completely untested**, so please be careful when executing:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "ROOT=Directory-Parent" & rem /* (set this to `%~dp0.` to specify the parent directory of the
                              rem     batch file, or to `.` to for current working directory) */
set "YEAR=2019"  & rem // (set the year just as a constant as it is unclear where to get it from)
set "MOVA="      & rem // (set this to `-sdel` if you want the files to be moved into the archive)

rem // Interate through the current working directory:
for /D %%d in ("%ROOT%\*.*") do (
    rem // Clear exclusion parameter for `7z`, reset flag that indicates if there are files left:
    set "EXCL=" & set "FLAG="
    rem /* Iterate through all files in the currently iterated directory, sorted from 
    rem    oldest to newest (`/O:D`), regarding the last modification date/time (`/T:W`);
    rem    the `findstr` part is to exclude the archive file itself if already present: */
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%f in ('
        dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:W "%%~d\*.*" ^| findstr /V /I /X /C:"%%~nxd%YEAR%.zip"
    ') do (
        rem // Exclusion parameter is not yet set in first loop iteration:
        if defined EXCL set "FLAG=#"
        rem // Exclusion parameter becomes set at this point:
        set "EXCL=-x!"%%f""
    )
    rem /* Flag is only set if there is one more file besides the one to exclude,
    rem    meaning that there are at least two files in total: */
    if defined FLAG (
        rem // Store folder information in variables to avoid loss of potentially occurring `!`:
        set "FOLDER=%%~fd" & set "NAME=%%~nxd"
        rem /* Toggle delayed expansion in order to be able to read variables that have been
        rem    set within the same block of parenthesised code (namely the `for` loops): */
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Execute the `7z` command line with dynamic parameters:
        ECHO 7z a -bd %MOVA% !EXCL! -x^^!"!NAME!%YEAR%.zip" "!FOLDER!\!NAME!%YEAR%.zip" "!FOLDER!\*.*"
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

I preceded the (potentionally dangerous) `7z` command line by `ECHO`, just for safety purposes.

Comment: It looks like now when it's run the second time it creates a zip inside the first zip. And then it if it's run a third time it creates a zip in the second zip that's in the first zip and so on.

Comment: Oh, seems I don't really understand the `-x!` option; perhaps it's necessary to specify the full path of the `.zip` or something? like `-x^^!"!FOLDER!\!NAME!%YEAR%.zip"`?