# How to compress all files modified in a specific year in each subfolder of a folder into one ZIP file per subfolder?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, zip, archive, 7zip

I've previously asked the following question and was helped with a great solution.

[How to compress all files with exception of newest file in each subfolder of a folder into one ZIP file per subfolder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613888/how-to-compress-all-files-with-exception-of-newest-file-in-each-subfolder-of-a-f)

Now at the end of the year I would like to modify this solution so that it zips any remaining files from last year into the existing zip file.

The directory structure is like this:

```
Directory-Parent
 ---Sub-Directory-1
 --------File1
 --------File2
 --------File3
 ---Sub-Directory-2
 --------File1
 --------File2
```

As mentioned and referred to in my previous question, I have a batch at the Directory-Parent level that will create a zip in each sub-directory of all the files except the latest file (or amount I specify). It also adds the year to the end of the zip file name.

So the result is:

```
Directory-Parent
 -Sub-Directory-1
 --------File1
 --------Sub-Directory-12019.zip
 ---Sub-Directory-2
 --------File1
 --------Sub-Directory-22019.zip
```

The following is the batch file solution I have from my previous question.  It zips all the files in each sub-directory (ignoring folders that I specify) into a zip file with the name of the directory appended by the current year.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FilesToIgnore=2"
set "theYear=%DATE:~-4%"
set "ListFile=%Temp%\%~n0.lst"
set "Move2=-sdel"      & rem // (set this to `-sdel` if you want the files to be moved into the archive)
set "FoldersToExclude=FoldersToExclude.txt"
del "%ListFile%" 2>nul
REM for /D %%I in (*) do call :CompressFiles "%%I"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD-H /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /V /X /G:"%FoldersToExclude%"') do call :CompressFiles "%%I"
goto EndBatch

:CompressFiles
pushd %1
set "ZipFile=%~nx1%theYear%.zip"
for /F "skip=%FilesToIgnore% eol=| delims=" %%J in ('dir /A-D /B /O-D /TW 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /C:"%ZipFile%"') do >>"%ListFile%" echo %%J
if exist "%ListFile%" (
    echo Compressing files in directory %1 ...
    echo 7z a %Move2% -bso0 -i"@%ListFile%" -mx5 -scsDOS "%ZipFile%"
    7z a %Move2% -bso0 -i"@%ListFile%" -mx5 -scsDOS "%ZipFile%"
    del "%ListFile%"
)
popd
goto :EOF

:EndBatch
pause
endlocal
```

I cannot figure out how to modify this to instead zip all files with a specified (or previous) year.
I believe the answer is in the second `for` loop in the `dir` command.  Is there a way in the `dir` command to filter by date.
Is there a way to use `forfiles` command instead with `@fdate`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the execution of `dir /A-D /O-D /TW` in any directory results in printing the file names with date in format `dd.MM.yyyy` in first column, the time in second column, file size in third column and file name in last column, the second `for` command line can be replaced by `for /F "eol=| tokens=3*" %%J in ('dir /A-D /O-D /TW 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^[0123][0123456789]\.[01][0123456789]\.2019" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /C:"%ZipFile%"') do >>"%ListFile%" echo %%K` to create the list file with file names with last modification date in year `2019`.

Comment: Otherwise the regular expression search string `^[0123][0123456789]\.[01][0123456789]\.2019` must be adapted first to the local date format according to region/country configured for the account use on running this batch file.

Comment: `for` (`~t`), `dir` and `forfiles` all deal with dates/times in a locale-dependent manner, and there's no date/time data type, so it's quite hard to write a reliable script; PowerShell does support real date/time values, perhaps you want to switch? if not, @Mofi's comment provides a good starting point...

Comment: Thank you @aschipfl.  You're probably right, I really should use PowerShell instead.

Comment: @Mofi.  Thank you.  This seems to work for me.  I did have to change the regular expression and also the `token=3*` to `tokens=4*`.  The final line change for me was `for /F "eol=| tokens=4*" %%J in ('dir /A-D /O-D /TW 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^[01][0123456789]\/[0123][0123456789]\/2019" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /C:"%ZipFile%"') do >>"%ListFile%" echo %%K`

Comment: @skatercurt That's fine. So local date format is on your PC `MM/dd/yyyy`. It would be interesting for me why `tokens=4*` was needed on your PC. What contains the additional column? `dir` outputs with configured country Austria a line with a file name like `06.01.2019  14:43            61.565 test file.txt`. I would be interested in how this line is output by `dir` with country __?__ configured in Windows region settings to get more knowledge on other output formats. Please would you be so kind and post in a comment how a line with a file name looks on your PC and let me also know the country.

Comment: @Mofi My Region is set to `Canada` and my 'Regional format' is set to `Recommended [English (United States)]`.  The difference is the time format, my time is set at 12 hour and has AM or PM applied. eg `01/14/2020  11:43 AM             3,656 New Text Document-1-6.txt`.  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @skatercurt Thank you for the comment with the data I asked for. That is good to know for me for the future. I was not aware that in countries like Canada, USA and  UK using by default a 12 hour format there is one more column with AM/PM output by __DIR__ instead of using 24 hour format by __DIR__. That is really important to know for me for the future. Thank you once again.